# If we mention all the components in a single module, will this affect the code or processing time?

Tags: angular, angular-module

In an angular whatever component we create it should be present in declaration[] of root module. if we generate own module which will consist our component and then custom module if imported in root module, can doing this task will get more time? or more load?
Else If we mention all the components in a single module, will this affect the code or processing time?

Comment: I sugest you to read this, it will explain everything: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: mentioning all the components in a single module is not a good practice, you cannot divide code in chunk to load later.

Comment: i've read doc. sir i want to know difference and how these both techniques affect the code

Comment: If you use lazy loaded modules - you will have better performance -  https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/v/v2.3/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html.   You can find this out by doing search on internet - instead of expecting SO users to google for you and paraphrase the same.   If you specific question with respect to lazy loaded module - then, please do ask  - by showing what you have done so far and where you are stuck.